# Convert pthread_t to NSThread

Tags: ios, pthreads, nsthread

I need check whether **pthread_t** is main thread.
I want do it from current thread (not from **pthread_t** which I need check and not from main thread).

My code (**pt** is **pthread_t**)

```
NSThread *thread = CFBridgingRelease(pt);  // it works wrong
bool isMain = thread.isMainThread;
```

But I can't right convert **pthread_t** to **NSThread**.

How I can convert **pthread_t** to **NSThread**?

Or how I can check whether **pthread_t** is main thread?

Comment: @CodeBender I don't need thread id. I need check whether pthread_t is main thread

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented way to obtain an `NSThread` object for a thread identified by a `pthread_t`, so if ...

> I need check whether **pthread_t** is main thread.

... is really what you need to do then you are probably up a creek.

Some of the possible alternatives are

- using `NSThread` instead of pthreads altogether;
- ensuring that the main thread's `pthread_t` identifier is recorded somewhere where you can access it for comparison; and
- not relying on discriminating between the main thread and others in the first place.

Note also that `NSThread` -- at least the one I think you mean -- is an Apple thing.  If you want something more broadly portable then `NSThread` is a non-starter.